# Stored procedure in SQL not set to an instance of an object error vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, ssms

When trying to call and run a stored procedure stored in sql server management studio in vb.net, I receive an error saying that my stored procedure is not set to an instance of an object. I have tested to see that my stored procedure executes in sql, have a sub in my database class that runs a stored procedure(with no parameters), and called the procedure and passed it with the stored procedure name.

Here is my code for the two subs in my database class:

```
Public Sub RunProcedure(ByVal strName As String)

    ' CREATES INSTANCES OF THE CONNECTION AND COMMAND OBJECT
    Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection(mstrConnection)
    ' Tell SQL server the name of the stored procedure you will be executing
    Dim mdbDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strName, objConnection)
    Try
        ' SETS THE COMMAND TYPE TO "STORED PROCEDURE"
        mdbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ' clear dataset
        Me.mDatasetCustomer.Clear()
        ' OPEN CONNECTION AND FILL DATASET
        mdbDataAdapter.Fill(mDatasetCustomer, "tblCustomers")
        ' copy dataset to dataview
        mMyView.Table = mDatasetCustomer.Tables("tblCustomers")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("stored procedure is " & strName.ToString & " error is " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub GetAllUsingSP()
    ' purpose: get all customer records with stored procedure
    ' inputs:  none directly
    ' returns: all customer records
    RunProcedure("usp_Customers_Get_All")
End Sub
```

Here is the code in my actual web form where I call the sub:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        'get all customers from db
        DB.GetAllUsingSP()
        'set up gridview
        gvCustomers.DataSource = DB.CustDataset.Tables("tblCustomers")
        'bind data
        gvCustomers.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

If someone can help me understand what the problem is, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: When you throw a `new` exception you're essentially throwing away all the good exception details.  Remove that and just throw exception.  Can you debug your code and tell us where this is happening?

Comment: where are you setting up the store procedure name in the sql command?

Comment: @JonH - the error is occuring in this line:    Throw New Exception("stored procedure is " & strName.ToString & " error is " & ex.Message)

Comment: What is tblCustomers is that the name of your stored procedure?  Where in your code do you execute the sproc?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper- Not sure this is what you're asking, but I'm creating/ setting up the stored procedure name under stored procedures in sqlserver

Comment: Here's an example of how I call a sproc:  `using (SqlConnection conMyData = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("mySproc"))
                {
                    dbCommand.Connection = conMyData;
                    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ChecklistSubTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = checklistSubTypeID;
                    SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand = dbCommand};`

Comment: `resultsDataSet = new DataSet();
                    dbAdapter.Fill(resultsDataSet);
                }
            }`

Comment: Sorry had to post it in two comments due to its size.  You need to be able to pass a connection to the sproc (your db connection), the name of the sproc, and then either fill a dataset or `ExecuteNonQuery`